# Vertex AI Feature Store limits

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Vertex AI has [quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas#featurestore). Other than submitting very high quota requests, is there documentation on hard limits for all of the quotas? Things like "online serving requests per minute", "Concurrent batch jobs", and "Entity types across all featurestores" are pretty key constraints to know before committing to Vertex.

Comment: Hi @skeller, If you find my answer helpful do consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation on hard limits for quotas. However, if you want to increase your quota from the standard limits you can always request for a higher quota following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas#quota_increases) and the Vertex AI Engineering team will configure it for you.